# Replacing sugar with maple syrup

Tags: cake, sugar, maple-syrup

I have a cake recipe which, among its ingredients, requires using 300 gr of sugar and 120 gr of water.

If I wanted to replace the sugar with maple syrup, would I need to adjust also the amount of water or not? Online I have found that the conversion ratio is one cup of white sugar with 2/3 to 3/4 cup of maple syrup.

The entire recipe requires:

- 300 gr of flour
- 300 gr of sugar
- 3 eggs
- 120 gr water
- 100 gr of olive oil
- rising agent

My primary goal would be to reduce the glycemic sugar.

Comment: Please also check the method - sugar is not just for sweetness, it can be a significant structural component, e.g. when creaming butter and sugar.

Comment: Are you trying to get a maple flavor or have a better / lower glycemic sugar?  That will make a difference in potential answers, but Stephie is correct that the sugar plays an important role in cakes.